# Porting signing function in bash/openssl which uses an RSA private key file (PEM) to C#

Tags: c#, bash, openssl, chef-infra, rsa

I am attempting to write some C# code that will allow me to make requests to a Chef server. Following the [documentation for the chef server API](https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html), I am trying to get the canonical header signed in my C# code so that I can authenticate with the server and make requests.

I found the following script [in the chef docs](https://docs.chef.io/auth.html) (see under 'cURL') that works with my client certificate. Calling this script returns the expected response JSON from the server. The part of the script which is used to sign the canonical header is:

```
method="GET"
hashed_path=$(echo -n "/organizations/[org]/nodes" | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64) #where [org] is my organization
hashed_body=$(echo -n "" | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64)
timestamp=$(date -u "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

canonical_request="Method:$method\nHashed Path:$hashed_path\nX-Ops-Content-Hash:$hashed_body\nX-Ops-Timestamp:$timestamp\nX-Ops-UserId:$client_name"

auth_headers=$(printf "$canonical_request" | openssl rsautl -sign -inkey \
"$(_chef_dir)/${client_name}.pem" | openssl enc -base64 | _chomp |  awk '{ll=int(length/60);i=0; \
while (i<=ll) {printf " -H X-Ops-Authorization-%s:%s", i+1, substr($0,i*60+1,60);i=i+1}}')
```

The important part of the above snippet is `$(printf "$canonical_request" | openssl rsautl -sign -inkey "$(_chef_dir)/${client_name}.pem" | openssl enc -base64`.

I have some C# code I've adapted from [dotnet-chef-api on GitHub](https://github.com/lholman/dotnet-chef-api/blob/master/dotnet-chef-api/AuthenticatedRequest.cs) which I'm trying to make do the same thing. It uses the [BouncyCastle crypto libraries](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html) to sign the content.

```
private string Sign(string privateKey)
{
    var method = _method.ToString().ToUpperInvariant(); //evals to 'GET'
    var hashedPath = _requestUri.AbsolutePath.ToBase64EncodedSha1String(); //evals to hash of '/organizations/[org]/nodes'
    var contentHash = _body.ToBase64EncodedSha1String(); //evals to hash of empty string

    var canonicalHeader = $"Method:{method}\nHashed Path:{hashedPath}\nX-Ops-Content-Hash:{contentHash}\nX-Ops-Timestamp:{_timestamp}\nX-Ops-UserId:{_client}";
    var input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalHeader);

    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(privateKey))
    {
        var pemReader = new PemReader(stringReader);
        var key = ((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair) pemReader.ReadObject()).Private;

        var signer = new RsaDigestSigner(new NullDigest());
        signer.Init(true, key);
        signer.BlockUpdate(input, 0, input.Length);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(signer.GenerateSignature());
    }
}
```

I've verified via the debugger and lots of `echo` statements that the canonical header in my bash script is exactly the same as the canonical header in my C# code. However, I'm totally stuck on the signing portion. The code I pulled from the GitHub project is unchanged, but is generating a different Base64 string than what I'm getting from the bash script (with the timestamps removed).

How do I sign something in C# in the same way that it is signed with the openssl tool? I have tried switching `NullDigest' for other types, but have not found one that produces the same Base64 result as the openssl binaries. I'm also open to better ways to accomplish this if they exist within the .Net framework already.

Comment: I would not expect to base64 encode the hash before doing the signing with the private key. I guess the `ToBase64EncodedSha1String` is wrong and needs to be change such that the sha1 hash binary data is given straight to the RSA operation.

Comment: I would also look at padding. Note that `openssl` is by default using PKCS#1v1.5 for signing with RSA. Since you're using RSA operation directly, the padding might need to be generated before the RSA operation.

Comment: @oliv I've confirmed `ToBase64EncodedSha1String` produces the same result as the command `echo -n "" | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64`. I know everything meets what the chef API expects up until the signing portion. I'll look more at the padding, that's something I haven't looked into yet

Comment: Yes! It was the padding. I'll add an answer with my findings. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use PKCS#1v1.5 instead of using the RSA operation directly, as suggested by @oliv. The code in my C# method becomes:

```
private string Sign(string privateKey)
{
    var method = _method.ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
    var hashedPath = _requestUri.AbsolutePath.ToBase64EncodedSha1String();
    var contentHash = _body.ToBase64EncodedSha1String();
    var canonicalHeader = $"Method:{method}\nHashed Path:{hashedPath}\nX-Ops-Content-Hash:{contentHash}\nX-Ops-Timestamp:{_timestamp}\nX-Ops-UserId:{_client}";
    var input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalHeader);

    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(privateKey))
    {
        var pemReader = new PemReader(stringReader);
        var keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair) pemReader.ReadObject();

        var pkcs1Encoding = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaBlindedEngine());
        pkcs1Encoding.Init(true, keyPair.Private);
        var signature = pkcs1Encoding.ProcessBlock(input, 0, input.Length);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
    }
}
```